# Which chart using in this graph

Tags: charts, highcharts

What chart used to generate this graph.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH2Al.png
I can't find it on highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

That graph is is made of several charts.

From left: `area`, `pie`, `area`, `column`, `column`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a highcharts application, but as far as I'm concerned you have area, pie and bar charts on that picture.

You should check this [demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo) section.